# What's the best way to make a time from "Today" or "Yesterday" and a time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

Python has pretty good date parsing but is the only way to recognize a datetime such as "Today 3:20 PM" or "Yesterday 11:06 AM" by creating a new date today and doing subtractions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A library that I like a lot, and I'm seeing more and more people use, is [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) but unfortunately neither it nor the other traditional big datetime parser, [mxDateTime from Egenix](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) can parse the word "tomorrow" in spite of both libraries having very strong "fuzzy" parsers.

The only library I've seen that can do this is [magicdate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/magicdate/0.1.3).  Examples:

```
>>> import magicdate
>>> magicdate.magicdate('today')
datetime.date(2009, 2, 15)
>>> magicdate.magicdate('tomorrow')
datetime.date(2009, 2, 16)
>>> magicdate.magicdate('yesterday')
datetime.date(2009, 2, 14)
```

Unfortunately this only returns datetime.date objects, and so won't include time parts and can't handle your example of "Today 3:20 PM".

So, you need mxDateTime for that.  Examples:

```
>>> import mx.DateTime

>>> mx.DateTime.Parser.DateTimeFromString("Today 3:20 PM")
<mx.DateTime.DateTime object for '2009-02-15 15:20:00.00' at 28faa28>

>>> mx.DateTime.Parser.DateTimeFromString("Tomorrow 5:50 PM")
<mx.DateTime.DateTime object for '2009-02-15 17:50:00.00' at 2a86088>
```

EDIT: mxDateTime.Parser is only parsing the time in these examples and ignoring the words "today" and "tomorrow". So for this particular case you need to use a combo of magicdate to get the date and mxDateTime to get the time.  My recommendation is to just use python-dateutils or mxDateTime and only accept the string formats they can parse.

---

EDIT 2: As noted in the comments it looks python-dateutil can now handle fuzzy parsing.  I've also since discovered the [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) module that was developed for use in Chandler and it works with the queries in this question:

```
>>> import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
>>> import parsedatetime.parsedatetime_consts as pdc
>>> c=pdc.Constants()
>>> p=pdt.Calendar(c)
>>> p.parse('Today 3:20 PM')
((2010, 3, 12, 15, 20, 0, 4, 71, -1), 3)
>>> p.parse('Yesterday 11:06 AM')
((2010, 3, 11, 11, 6, 0, 3, 70, -1), 3)
```

and for reference here is the current time:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 12, 15, 23, 35, 951652)
```

Comment: My recommendation is to file a bug with myDateTime; it shouldn't be that hard to add today/yesterday/tomorrow?

Comment: @Van: Maybe `dateutil` has improved since you posted this. Using dateutil version 1.4.1, `dateutil.parser.parse('tomorrow at 5:50 pm',fuzzy=True)` returns `datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 12, 17, 50)`.

Comment: @~unutbu: Thanks, that's good to know.  I've also since discovered the parsedatetime module at http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/ which is working out well on a very small project.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: it is much harder than you think, because it is l10n aware and can parse date that are not in English. It can't just add 'tomorrow', it would have to add other languages equivalent. Plus, how do you handle bad spelling, abreviations, etc. ? You must put a limit somewhere. If you need something only for english and 'tomorrow', it's not that hard to hack it yourself. Filling a bug ticket feels overkill.

Comment: @e-satis: I don't follow you; "overkill" implies the bug is too simple (which it isn't according to your own analysis). Also the language issue is easy to solve: Just provide a way to specify different languages. When programmers from any place can add their translations, they will. Right now, they can't. Bad spelling can't be solved by a computer today, so why bother?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: it's overkill to make a right full implementation in another lib VS just hack your own solution matching your specific case. You are obviously not maintaining a big open source project to suggest playing with others people time so easily.

Comment: @unutbu: using dateutil 1.5, `"tomorrow"` doesn't seem to work. And looking at your example, it wasn't working with 1.4.1 either... The `fuzzy` parameter simply enables skipping of unparsable parts.

Comment: @thm: Hm. Indeed you are right. Another solution to add to the list is Paul McGuire's `pyparsing` with [deltaTime](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/deltaTime.py).

Comment: MagicDate seems to be able to parse timestamps as well. Parsing the string `3 days, 3 hours ago` returns `2014-10-16 01:35:47.603682`, of type `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`.

Answer (score -3):

I am not yet completely up to speed on Python yet, but your question interested me, so I dug around a bit.

Date subtraction using [**`timedelta`**](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is by far the most common solution I found.

Since your question asks if that's the **only** way to do it, I checked out the strftime format codes to see if you could define your own.  Unfortunately not.  From Python's [strftime documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#id1):

> ... The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common.
>
> The following is a list of all the format codes that the C standard (1989 version) requires ...

Anyhow, this isn't a definitive answer, but maybe It'll save others time barking up the wrong tree.