# Smart date interpretation

Tags: python, date-parsing

I can't remember which application I was using, but I do recall it having really neat date parsing/interpretation.

For example, you could type in 'two days ago' or 'tomorrow' and it would understand.

Any libraries to suggest? Bonus points if usable from Python.

Comment: http://www.rememberthemilk.com/ and GNU *at* "allow fairly complex time specifications"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552073/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-time-from-today-or-yesterday-and-a-time-in-pyth/552229#552229) for links to three Python date parsing libraries.  The one of these most commonly used is [python-dateutils](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) but unfortunately it can't handle all formats.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you are thinking of PHP's `strtotime()` function, the [Swiss Army Knife of date parsing](http://brian.moonspot.net/2008/09/20/strtotime-the-php-date-swiss-army-knife/):

> Man, what did I do before `strtotime()`.  Oh, I know, I had a 482 line function to parse date formats and return timestamps.  And I still could not do really cool stuff.  Like tonight I needed to figure out when Thanksgiving was in the US.  I knew it was the 4th Thursday in November.  So, I started with some math stuff and checking what day of the week Nov. 1 would fall on.  All that was making my head hurt.  So, I just tried this for fun.
>
> ```
> strtotime("thursday, november ".date("Y")." + 3 weeks")
> ```
>
> That gives me Thanksgiving.  Awesome.

Sadly, there does not appear to be a Python equivalent. The closest thing I could find is the [`dateutil.parser`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module.

Comment: You could run something like the following in python: [item for item in list(rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY,count=12,byweekday=rrule.TH(4),dtstart=datetime.date.today())) if item.month == 11][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'). This would calculate the dates for the 4th Thursday of every month for one year out. You then select the one where the month is November and you have the date for the next Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 2):

The simple one I have seen for python is [here](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/UnderDevelopment#toc0).

It uses pyparsing and is only a small script, but it does what you ask.  However, the advantage being it would be pretty easy to extend and improve on if needed. Pyparsing is relatively easy to learn as parsing goes.