# convert an integer number in a date to the month name using python

Tags: python, datetime, ubuntu, converters

I do have this string `'2013-07-01'` and I want to convert it to `July 1, 2013`
How to do that using python?

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169000/smart-date-interpretation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '2013-07-01'
>>> mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> print mydate.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
July 01, 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

To add `Haidro's` answer, you could do it in just one compact line:

```
>>> s = '2013-07-01'
>>> print datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'July 01, 2013'
```

Comment: oh yea, forgot that datetime objects have a strftime function

Comment: I like the one line solution!!! Always amazed about how one line could solve a problem in python!! thank you Developer!!!!