# Convert Datetime object of type: %B %D %Y

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date as:

```
'September 17, 2013'
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
2013-09-17
```

I tried this hint taken from this stackoverflow question [1]:

```
mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime("September 17, 2013", '%B %d, %y')
```

But it gives me an:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 13
```

What should I do?

[1] [convert an integer number in a date to the month name using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797171/convert-an-integer-number-in-a-date-to-the-month-name-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%Y` insetead of `%y`. the latter matches only 2 digits

```
%y  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ..., 99  
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.  1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("September 17, 2013", '%B %d, %y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 13
>>> x = datetime.datetime.strptime("September 17, 2013", '%B %d, %Y')
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 17, 0, 0)
>>>
```

and then,

```
x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = 'September 17, 2013'
if ',' in date_str:
# Convert the date string to a datetime object
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%B %d, %Y")
        
# Format the date object to the desired format
   formatted_date = date_obj.strftime("%Y/%-m/%-d")

print("Converted date:", formatted_date)
```